# jQuery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the Jquery file upload widget, http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I managed to get all the images to my database the way i wanted but i'm not able to view only the images that i want. in the index page it views all the images in the "files" folder.

I'm making an image gallery with multiple albums.

[image: Photos Table]

The image above shows my photos table. i have the name of the image and a number (in_album) telling me which album it's in. when I go to www.example.com/gallery.php/album?12 for example i want only those photos that have in_album = 12 viewed, not all the photos in the folder. i think i need to use JSON or something to achieve this, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Select all the photos in the desired folder, return JSON of the same, loop through the JSON to get the Image Links.

Comment: You need to filter it server side as result of an ajax request which made a database request. You could us a GET request like this: wwww.example.com/gallery.php/album?in_album=12  and code your server side logic. Hope its not chinese for you...

Comment: lol it kind of is. ive never worked with ajax before..

Answer (score 0):

Not useful, but it works:

```
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}


        {% if (file.in_album == '12') { %}


        <tr class="template-download fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview">
                    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                    {% } %}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">
                    {% if (file.url) { %}
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                    {% } else { %}
                        <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                    {% } %}
                </p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                    <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                {% } else { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
                    {% } %}


    {% } %}
    </script>
```